# 2D array using commandline parameters and passing to a function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I was trying to pass a 2D array to a function using command-line parameters.

First I have to escape the prototype error so used `int arr[][3]` but could not get through the `argv` error which is mentioned in the screenshot here.

Is it possible to pass a 2D array the way I am trying or am I just banging my head onto the wall [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void twoD_array(int arr[][3]);

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
     if(argc == 1)
     {
        printf("command line argument fails\n");
        return 0;
     }
     int i,j;
     int arr[atoi(argv[1])][atoi(argv[2])];
     twoD_array(arr);

     printf("Your 2D array is\n");
     for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
     {
         for(j = 0;j < atoi(argv[2]); j++)
         {
             printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
         }
             printf("\n");
     }
}

void twoD_array(int arr[atoi(argv[1])][atoi(argv[2])])
{
   int i,j;
   printf("enter elements of 2D array\n");
   for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
   {
       for(j = 0;j < atoi(argv[2]); j++)
       {
           scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
       }
            
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the dimensions as two more function arguments preceding the array argument, for example `void twoD_array(int y, int x, int arr[y][x]);`

Comment: i dont think so bcz same model was working perfectly fine when i was just passing a 2D array to a function without commandline parameters.it will be appreciated if you could do changes in the code as you wish and show

Comment: That was for `int arr[][3]` which relies on the inner dimension being `3` but the outer dimension is still unknown.

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: First store width and height to dedicated variables rather than playing with `atoi(argv[xxx])` all the time

Comment: The error message is plain-text.  You should post it as such, not a _screenshot_ of plain-text.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define a function like this:

```
void twoD_array(int arr[atoi(argv[1])][atoi(argv[2])])
{
    …
}
```

The variable `argv` is not in scope (undefined), and you can't use function calls like that in the function parameter list.

You could use VLA (variable-length array) notation, though:

```
void twoD_array(int rows, int cols, int arr[rows][cols])
{
    …
}
```

Support for this was non-existent in C90, is mandatory in C99, and is optional in C11 and C18. C23 will make VLA support in parameter lists mandatory once more, but support for local (automatic) allocation of stack VLA variables will be optional (but they can always be allocated dynamically via `malloc()` et al).

See C11 [§6.7.6.2 Array declarators](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2) and [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3).  They are not the most easily read sections of the standard, though.

Answer (score 0):

final answer:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include<string.h>
  void twoD_array(int arr[][3]);
  int ROW,COL;
  int main(int argc,char * argv[])
  {
       if(argc == 1)
       {
              printf("command line argument fails\n");
              return 0;
       }
       int i,j;
       int arr[atoi(argv[1])][atoi(argv[2])];
       ROW = atoi(argv[1]);
       COL = atoi(argv[2]);
       twoD_array(arr);

       printf("Your 2D array is\n");
       for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
       {
              for(j = 0;j < atoi(argv[2]); j++)
             {
                  printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
             }
          printf("\n");
       }
   }

   void twoD_array(int arr[ROW][COL])
  {
         int i,j;

         printf("enter elements of 2D array\n");
         for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
         {
                for(j = 0;j < COL; j++)
                {
                   scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
                }
            
         }

   }
```